# Memory Management with Repeating jQuery Datatables AJAX Calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, memory, datatables

I'm fairly new to javascript and jQuery, so please excuse any incorrect verbiage in my problem description.

**Background**: I have a site where I'm using the [Datatables](http://datatables.net) plugin for jQuery to display a live, realtime display of a SQL table.  The SQL query is processed in ASP.NET and returned to the client as a JSON object.  Right now, I'm only displaying ~500 records.

Once the JSON object has been parsed by the datatables plugin, I perform some conditional formatting of the table cells -- hence there could be some heavy DOM manipulation if I understand that concept correctly.  I've read that this can be where a lot of memory leaks can occur, but I also thought that jQuery was pretty solid at cleaning up after itself.

I'm using a setInterval timer to update the datatable periodically such that it displays changes in real time.

**My Problem**: Memory consumption of my site is out of control.  On every AJAX call (~every 2 sec), the memory usage for the page can jump as much as 2MB.  To throttle this back, I installed an [idle plugin](http://www.bedroomlan.org/coding/detecting-%E2%80%98idle%E2%80%99-and-%E2%80%98away%E2%80%99-timeouts-javascript) for jQuery to detect when the user is active on the site - and I reduce the AJAX calls to ~every 1 hour when the user is idle.  I heard that this can give more space for the browser to perform garbage collection.

What I find is that memory climbs pretty continuously while active, with a slight drop every 4 or 5 calls where it looks like some garbage collection is being performed.  Memory does not climb when the AJAX calls are reduced while the user is idle.  Below, I've pasted a stripped down version of my code (excluding some irrelevant snippets).  I'm sure it's not the cleanest code - but if someone could provide a pointer as to what might be causing the memory consumption -- or how I could reduce the consumption, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```
    //TIMER
    var updateFreq = 5000;
    var timer;

    setIdleTimeout(5000); // 5 seconds
    setAwayTimeout(50000); // 10 seconds
    document.onIdle = function() {
        clearInterval(timer);
        updateTable(3600000); //update once an hour
        //if (typeof (CollectGarbage) == "function") { CollectGarbage(); }
    }        
    document.onAway = function() { 
        clearInterval(timer);
        updateTable(3600000); //update once an hour
        //if (typeof (CollectGarbage) == "function") { CollectGarbage(); }
     }  
    document.onBack = function(isIdle, isAway) {
        clearInterval(timer);
        updateTable(5000); //update once every two seconds
    }
    //END TIMER

    var oTable;
    var oSettings;

$(document).ready(function() {
    oTable = $("#production_table").dataTable({
            "sDom": '<"TT"T><"tab"t><"F"fip>',
            "iDisplayLength": -1,
            "sAjaxSource": 'Data.ashx',
            // "sScrollY": y - 217,
            //"sScrollX": "100%",
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bDeferRender": true,
            // "bStateSave": true,
            "aaSorting": [[16, 'desc']],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            //        "bAutoWidth": false,
            "fnDrawCallback": function(oSettings) {
                addFormat();
                try {
                    $('td').disableTextSelect();
                }
                catch (err) {
                }
            },
            "fnServerData": function(sSource, aoData, fnCallback) {
                $.ajax({
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    url: sSource,
                    data: aoData,
                    success: fnCallback
                })
            },
            "fnInitComplete": function(oSettings, json) {
                //alert('DataTables has finished its initialisation.');
                //                    addFormat();

                //$('td').disableTextSelect();
            },
            // "bProcessing": true,
            "aoColumns": [
                    { "mDataProp": null, "bSortable": false },
                    { "mDataProp": "serial", "sClass": "serial" },
                    { "mDataProp": "us", "sClass": "us" },
                    { "mDataProp": "type", "sClass": "type" },
                    { "mDataProp": "compartment", "sClass": "compartment" },
                    { "mDataProp": "leg", "sClass": "leg", "bVisible": false },
                    { "mDataProp": "comp", "sClass": "comp", "bVisible": false },
                    { "mDataProp": "patient", "sClass": "patient", "bVisible": false },
                    { "mDataProp": "dob", "sClass": "dob", "bVisible": false },
                    { "mDataProp": "surgeon", "sClass": "surgeon", "bVisible": false },
                    { "mDataProp": "surgery", "sClass": "surgery", "bVisible": false }
//I've truncated this section slightly...
                ]

        });
    updateTable(updateFreq);
});



function updateTable(uF) {
    // Update the table using the fnReloadAjax call method
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var iStart = oSettings._iDisplayStart;
            oSettings = oTable.fnSettings();
            oTable.fnReloadAjax();
            //oTable.fnDisplayStart(oSettings, iStart, true);
        }, uF);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have posted this a long while ago.  What was causing this to spiral out of control was that I was requesting the entire data set (several thousand rows) every 2 seconds.

What I ended up doing to fix this was changing my data source such that on load, I would get all of the data from the source - but any time after that, I would pull from a different source that only returned changes since the last request.  It really cut down on the data being sent down.  As a result, memory usage was significantly cut down and garbage collection had no problems handling any slight climbs.